# Accessing data automatically assigned by force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am creating a network of nodes and edges using force layout. My application has some dynamic nodes (which can be any number determined by backend code). I am allowing the force layout to assign the x and y for these dynamic nodes by itself which it does on calling force.start() function.

Now, there are a different set of nodes which are moving over the edges(eg. cars moving on roads) connecting the static and dynamic nodes.  For this animation, I need to get the x and y values from the force.nodes() which it has assigned to the dynamic nodes. I tried the normal dot operator to get the values but it fails to return the actual value.

Below is one of the value of node

```
[09:13:07.505] ({name:"D_Exit_0", dynamic:true, act_cap:-1, danger:0, index:0, weight:1, x:3014.087389427884, y:513.2901517247882, px:3013.9965777253265, py:513.0782974731648})
```

The x and y values here are assigned by the force layout.
When I tried node.x, it is returning me a value I had accessed just before accessing this node. However, when I directly print the node using console.log(node) it gives the above output.

Kindly let me know how I can get the dynamic data assigned by the force layout itself i.e. value x: 3014.08.. in above case?

Answer (score 1):

`force.nodes()` should return an array of all the nodes. To get the `x` value from one the first one, use `force.nodes()[0].x` ([documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-nodes)).

To animate something along the connection between the nodes, you might better off working with `force.links()`, which returns all the links between nodes. If you're working off of one of the examples, there should be a line of code similar to `var link = svg.selectAll(".link")`; if there is you could, for example, slowly turn all the links green with:

```
> link.transition().duration(5000).style("stroke", "green")
```

If you have any more questions, post the code you have so far on jsfiddle or bl.ocks.org.